# Mysqli запрос и массив

Tags: mysqli, массивы, mysql

Добрый вечер!

Написал запрос, который при оформлении заказа вычитает из имеющегося количества товара то количество, которое ввел заказчик при оформлении. Дело в том, что если один товар заказать, то вычитание происходит, а вот если 2 и более товаров заказать, то вычитание происходит по последнему id товара. Скорее всего, надо запрос указать массивом, если возможно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
      $id = $_POST['na']; // уникальный id товара
      $vnal = $_POST['nas']; // имеющееся количество товара
      $kolvo = $_POST['nass']; // количество введенное заказчиком          
        $query = "UPDATE  goods SET 
                    nalichies = ( $vnal - $kolvo ) WHERE
                    goods_id = $id";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

        if(mysqli_affected_
```

**То есть $_POST-ом надо вытащить значения каждого товара, а сейчас у меня вытаскивает только значения последнего товара и подставляется в запрос. Не могу решить.**

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ.**

Ну вот я добавляю в input:

```
<input type="text" name="na[]" value="<?=$item['goods_id']?> />

<input type="text" name="nas[]" readonly value="<?=$item['nalichies']?>" />

<input id="id<?=$key?>" class="kolvo" type="text" name="nass[]" value="<?=$item['qty']?>" />
```

и вот так выглядит:

```
      $id = $_POST["na"][0];
      $vnal = $_POST["nas"][0];
      $kolvo = $_POST["nass"][0];
        $query = "UPDATE  goods SET 
                    nalichies = ( $vnal - $kolvo ) WHERE
                    goods_id = $id";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Берет теперь, наоборот, не последний товар из множества, а первый только считает.

Comment: Ну вот на подобный вопрос можно было бы и придумать решение, если бы по крайней мере имена переменных и параметров были осмысленно именованы.

Где тут пример ситуации «если 2 и более товаров заказать»?

Comment: @Bars, Как я напишу пример, если сам не знаю, как это реализовать! В корзине если лежат сразу несколько товаров. Мне и надо запрос, чтобы обновлял все эти лежащие товары при оформлении заказа, а он обновляет только один товар. Ну проименуйте посвоему

Comment: Хорошо, какие данные приходят, когда человек «оплачивает» содержимое корзины? Ну ведь не `$id = $_POST['na']; // уникальный id товара`, а по меньшей мере `$id = $_POST['na']; // array — массив id товаров`. А что остальные переменные?

Comment: @Bars, Ну у меня они ничего не оплачивают в процессе оформления. $id = $_POST['na']; я беру для того, чтобы знать, к какому id товара изменить количество товара (имеющееся в наличии).

Допустим, было 6, он закал 3 => 6-3=3 - остаток. А $kolvo = $_POST['nass'], это поле, куда заказчик вводит сколько он хочет заказать товаров. А данные у меня все уходят отлично в таблицу с заказами. Эту функцию я реализую, для того, чтобы у товара автоматически писало "Нет в наличии" (если уже поле nalichies = 0).

Comment: > $id = $_POST['na']; я беру для того, чтобы знать, к какому id товара изменить количество товара

Но проблема в том, что самих товаров (позиций то бишь — единиц номенклатуры) может быть больше одного, верно? Отсюда вопрос: что при этом хранится в остальных членах массива `$_POST`?

Если проблема не в этом, если «корзина» рассчитана только на 1 тип товара, то `$_POST['nas']` вообще не нужна. В таком случае нужен запрос:

    $query = 'UPDATE goods SET 
              nalichies = nalichies - '.intval($kolvo).'
              WHERE goods_id = '.intval($id);

Comment: @Bars, Да Вы правильно поняли, что их может быть больше одного, и поэтому согласен - "что при этом хранится в остальных членах массива $_POST" - да, не известно, по этому пересчет делает только по одному товара из всех, а так корзина рассчитана на множество товаров.

Comment: > да, не известно, по этому пересчет делает только по одному товара из всех, а так корзина рассчитана на множество товаров.

Тогда неплохо было бы узнать, [что](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php) [же](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php) [в них](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php) [хранится](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php).

Недостаточно вводных данных.

Comment: @Bars, извиняйте) Есть варианты решения?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays